# How to select span which contains numbers in text using regex in xpath

Tags: html, regex, xpath

Now I'm using 
`//span[text()='1'] | //span[text()='2'] | //span[text()='3']` 
but it looks not good enough.
Could anyone please tell me how to do same thing using something more elegant, for example
`//span[text()='[^0-9]']`

Comment: Which version of xpath?

Comment: version is 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `matches()` function:

```
//span[matches(.,'[0-9]')]
```

Comment: Does XPath support RegEx?

Comment: Version 2 does, version 1 does not.